# The best way to add a concatenated string of multiple fields to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 14 datetime fields in my database. Ive been asked to return a single field of the 14 dates as one string field. Right now my stored proc looks kinda like this:

```
convert(varchar, [DTMON_F],108) as mondayFrom,
   convert(varchar,[DTMON_T],108) as mondayTo,
   convert(varchar,[DTTUES_F],108) as tuesdayFrom,
   convert(varchar,[DTTUES_T],108) as tuesdayTo,
```

I want to have a single field called extendedDetails that is in the format HHmm - HHmm, HHmm - HHmm

This returns for example "10:20:00" so I'll have to somehow cut this to look like "1020" and then somehow concat all of them.

```
convert(varchar, [DTMON_F],108) as mondayFrom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE
  ( 
   convert(char(5), [DTMON_F],108) + ' - ' +  
   convert(char(5),[DTMON_T],108) + ' - ' +
   convert(char(5),[DTTUES_F],108) + ' - ' +
   convert(char(5),[DTTUES_T],108) + ' - ' +
    ...
     , ':', '') AS whatever 
FROM MYTABLE
```

Comment: Can you look at my query above I dont think I know how to add your code in

Comment: Almost that returns this:1030 - 2200 - 1030 - 2200 - , I need 1030-2200, 1030-2200